# Getting distinct columns from postgresql in django model

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have a postgresql table with columns that have repeating data like this which was created using a django model:

[image]

In order to get distinct values of a column, we use a postgre command something like this:

```
SELECT distinct degree_code FROM studentapp_deg_course_cat
```

But i want to get this data as an array using python. How do i get distinct objects from the columns of a table in python?

Comment: the same way you get any data from a query. just because it's `select distinct` doesn't change how you retrieve it. you'll get 0 or more rows of data that you fetch and store.

Comment: can you tell me how to get data using python?

Comment: Do you want to get this inside django or in a standalone python script?

Comment: i want to get it inside django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In django you can use the [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) method when querying your model.

So something like this

```
models.YourModel.objects.order_by('degree_code').distinct('degree_code')
```

As you are using PostgreSQL note the docs which state

> On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in
>   order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should
>   apply. This translates to a SELECT DISTINCT ON SQL query. Here’s the
>   difference. For a normal distinct() call, the database compares each
>   field in each row when determining which rows are distinct. For a
>   distinct() call with specified field names, the database will only
>   compare the specified field names.

Comment: is this operation equivalent to the get operation?

Comment: no - get() will raise an exception if more than match is found and does not return a QuerySet object, while distinct() returns a QuerySet object which is iterable. They are both part of the QuerySet API though, and similar in the sense that you use them to access data stored in your database. Open you your django shell and try them out to see the difference